# Return String from AsyncTask in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have been trying all day, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to return a string from AsyncTask in BroadcastReceiver but I am not sure how to do it correctly (new at Java). I have an app that accesses the internet and reads a text file and this text file is a long string. I delimit the string into an array and use it contents that way. In the BroadcastReceiver I want to broadcast (update) the temperature from the weather station every 10-60 minutes depending on what the user sets-up on the notification bar.

Should I use a Thread instead of AsyncTask?
The error I get is with the following line:

> String output = new GetWeatherValues().execute(weburi);

I also tried the following code that is commented out:

> //        GetWeatherValues clientraw = new GetWeatherValues();
>
> //        clientraw.doInBackground(weburi);

Below is my Class, please help, I have searched a lot and still no result.

```
public class UpdateFrequency extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Notification Text Elements
private final CharSequence tickerText = "Weather Updated";
private CharSequence contentTitle = "Weather at ";
private final CharSequence contentText = "Current Temperature is ";

final String http = "http://";
final String clientraw = "/clientraw.txt";
String weburi, webUrl;

// Notification Action Elements
private Intent notificationIntent;
private PendingIntent mContentIntent;

// Notification ID to allow for future updates
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

final String PREFS_NAME = "SettingsFile";

SharedPreferences settings;
public String[] parts;

public static final String WebAddress = "webAddressKey";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("log_etag", "Entered Update Frequency");

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.contains(WebAddress)) {
        webUrl = settings.getString(WebAddress, "");
        weburi = http + webUrl + clientraw;
        Log.e("log_etag", "WEB URL Frequency " + weburi);
    }
    
//      GetWeatherValues clientraw = new GetWeatherValues(); 
//      clientraw.doInBackground(weburi);

    String output = new GetWeatherValues().execute(weburi);

    String[] parts = output.split(" ");

    ArrayList<String> clientRawData = new ArrayList<String>();
    clientRawData.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
    
    //Time of last update from weather station.
    contentTitle = contentTitle + parts[29] + ":" + parts[30]; 
    
    Log.e("log_etag", "Content Title " + contentTitle);
    
    // The Intent to be used when the user clicks on the Notification View
    notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // The PendingIntent that wraps the underlying Intent
    mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Build the Notification
    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
            context).setTicker(tickerText)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(contentText).setContentIntent(mContentIntent);
    

    // Get the NotificationManager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager:
    mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notificationBuilder.build());
}



private class GetWeatherValues extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
            
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        
                    try {

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        // get url data
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(weburi);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
                        // convert response to string
                        try {
                            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),
                                    8);

                            // read one line of code, file is one whole string.
                            try {

                                String returnData = reader.readLine();
                                webs.close();
                                return returnData;

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("log_tag",
                                        "Error in displaying textview "
                                                + e.toString());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("log_tag",
                                    "Error converting string " + e.toString());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag",
                                "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

                } 
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't run an async task in broadcast receiver. After the `onReceive` method finishes consider the receiver instance unusable. Use the receiver to launch an `IntentService` or `Service` which will do the actual work.

Comment: Google "EventBus". You can use it to post data from services to activities or between anything pretty much.

Comment: What about a Running a Thread? Is that also a bad idea?

Comment: Unless you need a context, you should be fine. BUT! `IntentService` runs on a background thread (so you can use HTTP) and gives you a context. And since you wouldn't post back the result to the receiver (which has ended by this point) it fits perfectly.

Comment: Ah I see, I was running the HTTP in a Runnable Thread and changed it to AsyncTask as I read it was better.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is OK when used in an activity (or rather retained fragment). If you need to decouple it you use receiver-service pair with result posting to whoever wants it (here comes in the event bus). Or the service writes to a content provider which you observe in your activity using `CursorLoader` (again there's no direct connection between the service and the activity). I'm just tossing ideas, be sure to check the actual answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is to override onPostExecute() in Async Task have a look at this link for [How to use AsyncTask correctly in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)

onPostExecute() allow to handle your things on UI Thread.

and here you can access your String (String returnData)

and you can also return value from async-task for that have look at this link [How to handle return value from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624193/how-to-handle-return-value-from-asynctask) 
but i will prefer for you not to that cos i will be a little bit complicated

a piece of code

```
private class ABC extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          //here your code

        return returnData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String returnedData) {
       //
   String[] parts = returnedData.split(" ");
   ArrayList<String> clientRawData = new ArrayList<String>();
   clientRawData.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));

   //Time of last update from weather station.
   contentTitle = contentTitle + parts[29] + ":" + parts[30]; 

   Log.e("log_etag", "Content Title " + contentTitle);

   // The Intent to be used when the user clicks on the Notification View
   notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

   // The PendingIntent that wraps the underlying Intent
    mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Build the Notification
     Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
        context).setTicker(tickerText)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText).setContentIntent(mContentIntent);


    // Get the NotificationManager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager:
    mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
        notificationBuilder.build());

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, you moved the code onto onPostExecute(), According to one of the links you showed me it states that I should do UI updates in this method. How do I get the context in this method?

Comment: if that answer is satisfies your problem then kindly accept it

Comment: Just one last question, how do I get the context in this method, before it was being passed into the onReceive method.

Comment: replace context with MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: The context from a broadcast receiver will not work after the `onReceive` method is finished. Which is before the `AsyncTask` finishes.

Comment: so Create Context mContext on the top of calss and in onReceive method what you have to do is mContext=context; now use mContext where-ever you want to use in that class

Comment: I tried and it gave me this error **No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope** on the get notification manager.

Comment: wthat do you want to do with onReceive Context

Comment: you can get context By MainActivity.this if onReceive finishes this will work

Comment: It was in the pending intent and notification builder that had the context underlined. I got no errors in the code now but when I compile and run on a device,it is giving me an HTTP error in connection, but the URL is there and is correct. The error is **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

Comment: Ah a quick question, in order to run the AsyncTask I have the following: **GetWeatherValues clientraw = new GetWeatherValues(); 
  clientraw.doInBackground();**

Comment: what you have to do is   new ABC().execute(yoururl);

Comment: Excellent that worked, thanks @MoubeenFarooqWarar and Eugen Pechanc