# AsyncTask use in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, kotlin

I have a problem with AsyncTask in Kotlin , I'm actually new so please be cool :)

So the problem here , is that I would like to use the result value which is in onPostExecute(), in another class

Let me show you my code, Here is ProviderAsync() class in my Provider.kt file ( I just create an array of Hashmap which I want to use) :

```
class ProviderAsync() : AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Any>, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>>() {

var allThings: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>> = arrayListOf()
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: HashMap<String, Any>): ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>? {
    for (i in 0..2000) {
        val thing = hashMapOf("Loc" to "fr", "name" to "class", "Id" to "23", "tuto" to "fr", "price" to 44)
        allThings.add(thing )
    }
    return null
}

override fun onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute()
    // ...
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    // what can I do Here
}
```

And now here is my getThings() method in another file where i want to use the result value to get all elements of my Arraylist :

```
fun getThings(context: Context) {
        ProviderAsync().execute()
        var values = // Here i want the RESULT send from my AsyncTask
         for (i in 0..values.size) {

                        var myObject = convertToMyObject(values[i])
                        allTickets.add(myObject)
                    }
        }
```

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: First of all let me know why are you not writing async task in the same class in which you want to use returned value?

Comment: It's my architecture , I want that my Provider do AsyncTask and sends datas to my Manager

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624316/7804719).

Comment: Any reason why you are using `HashMap<String, Any?>` instead of something like a `class`?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of Kotlin's functional nature:

```
class ProviderAsync(private val callback: (things: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>) -> Unit) : AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Any>, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>>() {

    var allThings: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>> = arrayListOf()
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: HashMap<String, Any>): ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>? {
        for (i in 0..2000) {
            val thing = hashMapOf("Loc" to "fr", "name" to "class", "Id" to "23", "tuto" to "fr", "price" to 44)
            allThings.add(thing)
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        //callback function to be executed after getting the result
        callback(result)
    }
}
```

then split the the callback logic in a separate function to pass it to `ProviderAsync` constructor:

```
fun getThings(context: Context) {
        ProviderAsync(::asyncTaskCallback).execute()
}

fun asyncTaskCallback(values: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>) {
    for (i in 0..values.size) {

        var myObject = convertToMyObject(values[i])
        allTickets.add(myObject)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2020 `AsyncTask` is **DEPRECATED**. It doesn't mean that the class will be removed any time soon, it means that Google is recommending that you move to something else. The [docs recommend to use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) the standard `java.util.concurrent` or [Kotlin concurrency utilities](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) instead.

Using the last one we can implement it as the following:

1. Create generic extension function on `CoroutineScope`:

   ```
    fun <R> CoroutineScope.executeAsyncTask(
            onPreExecute: () -> Unit,
            doInBackground: () -> R,
            onPostExecute: (R) -> Unit
    ) = launch {
        onPreExecute()
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // runs in background thread without blocking the Main Thread
            doInBackground()
        }
        onPostExecute(result)
    }
   ```
2. Use the function with any `CoroutineScope`:

   - In [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

     ```
     class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

         fun someFun() {
             viewModelScope.executeAsyncTask(onPreExecute = {
                 // ... runs in Main Thread
             }, doInBackground = {
                 // ... runs in Worker(Background) Thread
                 "Result" // send data to "onPostExecute"
             }, onPostExecute = {
                 // runs in Main Thread
                 // ... here "it" is the data returned from "doInBackground"
             })
         }
     }
     ```
   - In `Activity` or `Fragment`:

     ```
     lifecycleScope.executeAsyncTask(onPreExecute = {
         // ... runs in Main Thread
     }, doInBackground = {
         // ... runs in Worker(Background) Thread
         "Result" // send data to "onPostExecute"
     }, onPostExecute = {
         // runs in Main Thread
         // ... here "it" is the data returned from "doInBackground"
     })
     ```

   To use `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope` add next line(s) to dependencies of the app's **build.gradle** file:

   ```
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION" // for viewModelScope
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION" // for lifecycleScope
   ```

   At the time of writing `final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.3.0-alpha05"`