# AsyncTask return a boolean while retrieving information from a Json

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I want to check if a user is registered or not in a database, and if it is get the information of the user.

Normally, when I retrieve the information from the server, I put in the `Json` a variable saying if the user exists or not. Then in `onPostExecute(Void result)` i treat the `Json`, so i don't need the `AsyncTask` to return any value.

Before I was calling the AsyncTask as follows:

```
task=new isCollectorRegistered();
task.execute();
```

But now i'm trying a different approach. I want my asynktask to just return a boolean where i called the `AsyncTask`.

the `AsyncTask` looks as follows:

```
public class isCollectorRegistered extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    int TAG_SUCCESS1;
    private static final String TAG_COLLECTOR = "collector";
    public String collector;
    JSONArray USER = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Checks on the server if collector is registered
        try {
            jObj = ServerUtilities.UserRegistered(context, collector);
            return null;
        } finally {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {

            String success = jObj.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
            Log.d(TAG_COLLECTOR, "Final Info: " + success);

            //This if sees if user correct
            if (Objects.equals(success, "1")){
                //GOOD! THE COLLECTOR EXISTS!!
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG_COLLECTOR, "JSON parsing didn't work");
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked several posts, but I still havent found out the way to retrieve the boolean where I call the Asynktask, something like this :

```
task=new isCollectorRegistered();
task.execute();
boolean UserRegistered = task.result();
```

What would be the right approach? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458258/return-value-from-async-task-in-android

Comment: @ritesht93 thank you! so in fact is impossible to retrieve a value once the AsyncTask is executing because it is running a totally different thread no?

Comment: yes `doInBackground()` executes in a different thread, however you can pass values from  `doInBackground()` to `publishProgress()` or to `onPostExecute()`(these 2 methods run on activity's UI thread and you can use them to persist your values)

Comment: @ritesht93 - did you check out my answer below? What do you think about the approach I use? Lemme know. O&O!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `AsyncTask` you must subclass it. `AsyncTask` uses generics and varargs. The parameters are the following `AsyncTask <TypeOfVarArgParams , ProgressValue , ResultValue>` .

An `AsyncTask` is started via the `execute()` method.

The `execute()` method calls the `doInBackground()` and the `onPostExecute()` method.

`TypeOfVarArgParams` is passed into the `doInBackground()` method as input, `ProgressValue` is used for progress information and `ResultValue` must be returned from `doInBackground()` method and is passed to `onPostExecute()` as a parameter.

In your case you are passing `Void` to your `AsyncTask` : `isCollectorRegistered extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` so you can't get your result from the thread.
please read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) to a deep understand of the AsyncTask in Android

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is exactly what you were looking for,  Alvaro...
NOTE: I tweaked your code to make it more sensible, but I tried to stick to as much of your original code as possible...

```
    public class RegisterCollector extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_COLLECTOR = "collector";

        int TAG_SUCCESS1;
        String[] strArray;
        JSONArray USER = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        public String collector;
        private AppCompatActivity mAct;  // Just incase you need an Activity Context inside your AsyncTask...
        private ProgressDialog progDial;

        // Pass data to the AsyncTask class via constructor -> HACK!!
        // This is a HACK because you are apparently only suppose to pass data to AsyncTask via the 'execute()' method.
        public RegisterCollector (AppCompatActivity mAct, String[] strArray) {
            this.mAct = mAct;
            this.strArray = strArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // AHAH!! - So we do need that Activity Context after all...*TISK* *TISK* @ Google **sigh**.
            progDial = ProgressDialog.show(mAct, "Please wait...", "Fetching the strawberries & cream", true, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Checks on the server if collector is registered
            try {
                jObj = ServerUtilities.UserRegistered(context, collector);
                return true;  // return whatever Boolean you require here.
            } finally {
                return false;  // return whatever Boolean you require here.
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progDial.dismiss();
            try {

                String success = jObj.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                Log.d(TAG_COLLECTOR, "Final Info: " + success);

                // This 'if' block checks if the user is correct...
                if (Objects.equals(success, "1")){
                    //GOOD! THE COLLECTOR EXISTS!!
                }

                // You can then also use the Boolean result here if you need to...
                if (result) {
                    // GOOD! THE COLLECTOR EXISTS!!
                } else {
                    // Oh my --> We need to try again!! :(
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG_COLLECTOR, "JSON parsing didn't work");
                Toast.makeText(mAct, "JSON parsing FAILED - Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

...then if you want to use the generated Boolean data outside the AsyncTask class try the following:
.

```
    RegisterCollector regisColctr = new RegisterCollector((AppCompatActivity) this, String[] myStrArry);
    AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> exeRegisColctr = regisColctr.execute("");
    Boolean isColctrRegistered = false;
    try {
        isColctrRegistered = exeRegisColctr.get();  // This is how you FINALLY 'get' the Boolean data outside the AsyncTask...-> VERY IMPORTANT!!
    } catch (InterruptedException in) {
        in.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (isColctrRegistered) {
        // Do whatever tasks you need to do here based on the positive (i.e. 'true') AsyncTask Bool result...
    } else {
        // Do whatever tasks you need to do here based on the negative (i.e. 'false') AsyncTask Bool result...
    }
```

There you go - I think this is what you were looking for (originally). I always use this approach whenever I need Async data externally, and it has yet to fail me...
.