# android - finish the current activity only after the asynctask finishes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have implement task by interface and callback function. When the user got account wrong, the error message comes up and there are no errors at that point. However, the app stops unfortunately when the user login successfully.

Java:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish();
} 

// start this activity from MainActivity when the button is pressed
public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse{
    ...
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.delegate = this;
    backgroundTask.execute("login",user_ac_s,user_pw_s);

    public void processFinish(){
        if(!MainActivity.user_ID.equals("0"))
            finish();
    }
}

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ 
    ...
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    ...
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(task.equals("get_userID")){
            MainActivity.user_ID = result;
            delegate.processFinish();
        }
        if(task.equals("register") || task.equals("login")){
            Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(result.contains("success")){
                BackgroundTask get_userID_task = new BackgroundTask(context);
                get_userID_task.execute("get_userID",user_ac);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
       --------- beginning of crash

> 08-04 05:53:11.807 2667-2667/com.example.kwei.minigame1
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.kwei.minigame1, PID: 2667
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void com.example.kwei.minigame1.AsyncResponse.processFinish()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.kwei.minigame1.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:132)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.kwei.minigame1.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:26)
>                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: "stops unfortunately" means there's a logcat. Please include it in the question

Comment: Your _delegate_ is null

Comment: But I did backgroundTask.delegate = this; in login.class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

> AsyncResponse delegate = null;

`delegate` is null. You haven't initialized that !

**Edit:**

Make constructor

```
  public AsyncResponse delegate;

  public BackgroundTask(AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delagate;
  }
```

Now execute your async task with

```
  BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(new AsyncResponse()......);
  backgroundTask.delegate = this;// Comment this 
  backgroundTask.execute("login",user_ac_s,user_pw_s);
```

`this` keyword defines the activity's context in your case but actually you need to get for `AsyncResponse`.

Comment: how about backgroundTask.delegate = this in the class login ;

Comment: _this_ means what  ? You need to pass your delegate to in async constructor

Comment: backgroundTask.delegate = this change the variable delegate in object backgroundTask, isn't it?

Comment: new AsyncResponse() cannot be allowed as AsyncResponse is interface or abstract.

Comment: Because you have already implements that. So change   `BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);`

Comment: It works now. What is the difference between `backgroundTask.delegate = this;` in login and `this.delegate = delagate;` in constructor?

Comment: This _backgroundTask.delegate = this;_ will indicates that it is the context of activity but you need to use for your _AsyncResponse_ class.

Comment: If I want to implement the way like `backgroundTask.delegate = this;`. How can I change it?

Comment: You should implement your `AsyncResponse`  in your `BackgroundTask` class.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much.