# Return value from AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask

I have a class AsyncTask as an inner class to a fragment.

```
 public  class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,double[],double[]> {

    double posScoreb = 0.0;
    double negScoreb= 0.0;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

    @Override
    protected double[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        s = new SentiCalc(getActivity().getAssets());
        s.setInput(String.valueOf(params[0]));
        double[] set = new double[]{};


        try {
            set = s.getSenti();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        posScoreb = set[1];
        negScoreb = set[2];


        return new double[]{posScoreb,negScoreb};
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(double[] result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        result[0] = posScoreb;
        result[1] = negScoreb;
        delegate.processFinish(result);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

I am calling it from a method saveNote() inside the same fragment.`

```
    asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask()  ;
    asyncTask.delegate =this;
    asyncTask.execute(content);
```

I want AsyncTask class to return values inside a result(double array) to saveNote method. As shown in this,  **How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?.**
I created an interface and made my fragment class to implement it.

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
void processFinish(double[] output);}
```

As a result of which I am able to get the result inside a method processFinish
within the same fragment.

```
  @Override
public void   processFinish(double[] output) {
    double posScore,negScore;
    posScore = output[0];
    negScore = output[1];
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(posScore),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(negScore), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

How can I get this result inside a saveNote method from which I am calling AsyncTask class?

Comment: give direct idea of how we need to help you?

Comment: saveNote method is used to save note into database and AsyncTask is where a calculation of posScore and negScore is done based on a note which user enters inside the fragment. 
I want values of posScore and negScore to be accessed inside saveVote method.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458274/5215474

Comment: Yeah, that  helped .Thank you.