# Returning boolean from onPostExecute and doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Im looking solution for my problem.

I call an `AsyncTask` in my `Activity`:

```
login.execute(emailText.getText().toString(), passwordText.getText().toString());
```

In class Login i checking, if user exist.

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Void> {

public Login(Application application){
    repository = new Repository(application);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... body){
    try {
        user = repository.getUser(body[0], body[1]);
        if (user != null)
            return true; //wont work
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
   //i want to have bool value here that i will see in my activity
}
```

My question is, how to get `bool` value from `AsyncTask` when condition in if match? If it is any possible way to call method like that?

```
boolean valid = login.execute();
```

Thanks for help

Comment: AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> and you will be good to go . Also based on this the correct signature of this method will be void onPostExecute(Boolean result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `onPostExecute()` argument type to `Boolean` and then tell who would be interested in the result what happened.

For this last part you can have an interface and have that someone (intereste class) implement it.

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {

  private LoginListener listener;

  public Login(Application application, LoginListener listener){
    repository = new Repository(application);
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... body){
    try {
        user = repository.getUser(body[0], body[1]);
        if (user != null)
            return true; //wont work
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   listener.onLoginPerformed(result)
  }



  public static interface LoginListener{
    public void onLoginPerformed(Boolean result);
  }
}
```

Then suppose you want MainActivity to react upon the login:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActitvity implements LoginListener{
    ....
    // When you create the Login object, in onCreate() for example:
    // new Login(application, this); // this is the activity acting as listener...

    @Override public void onLoginPerformed(Boolean result){
        // do what you want to do with the result in Main Activity
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build your asyncTask like:

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private boolean valid;

@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... records) {
    // do work here
    user = repository.getUser(body[0], body[1]);
    if (user != null)
       valid = true;
    else
       valid = false;
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    callMyMethodWithTheUpdatedValue(valid);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you explain me more, what callMyMethodWithTheUpdatedValue(valid)` do and how to invoke it?

Comment: onPostExecute is called from the main thread right after doInbackground, so you can invoke any other method defined in the Activity with the correct value; instead of returning the value from the AsyncTask. Take a look at this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762539/5382017

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but reference two whole object with one `boolean` its too many i think. There is no siple way to return that `bool` from `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: If you want to react after onPostExecute you can modify a little bit your code and implement an interface to do that: basically you instantiate a listener in your activity and call the method of that listener from your onPostExecute(). Again follow this link for more informations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13815960/5382017

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below code:

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {

public Login(Application application){
    repository = new Repository(application);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... body){
    try {
        user = repository.getUser(body[0], body[1]);
        if (user != null)
            return Boolean.TRUE; //wont work
        else {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   //i want to have bool value here that i will see in my activity
   Log.e("POST_EXECUTE", "" + result);
}
```

Comment: And how to get `result` in my activity? I think its only thing that i dont understand

Comment: call activity method from `onPostExecute` with passing value

Answer (score 1):

The idea of AsyncTask is not to "get" a result but make something happen in the background without blocking the UI. Your approach will block the UI thread and until the server returns a response the app will be blocked and if that state stays for more than 5 secs the user will see a [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr)

But to answer your question:
In oder to get boolean result from the AsyncTask you need to extend the correct class, in your case it is: `AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>`, because the AsyncTask types are the following:

> *The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:*
>
> **Params**, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> **Progress**, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
>
> **Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

So to answer your question, your code will be:

```
//USAGE
Login l = new Login();
Boolean valid = l.execute("user", "pass").get(); 
/* but the UI thread will be 
blocked, meaning the following code will not be executed until the variable 
valid is populated */ 

//AsyncTask
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

public Login(Application application){
    repository = new Repository(application);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings){
    try {
        user = repository.getUser(strings[0], strings[1]);
        if (user != null)
            return true; //wont work
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   // this method is no longer needed since you will get the result directly 
   // from the doInBackground method

}
```

Nor for a solution that will actually work:
I suggest that every-time a user wants to log in the app should present a `progressDialog` window informing the user that it has to do a time consuming task, and after the process is completed inform the user of the status. 
In order to do this use the following code:

```
//USAGE
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        Login l = new Login();
        l.execute("user", "pass"); 
        /* but the UI thread will be 
        blocked, meaning the following code will not be executed until the                             
        variable valid is populated */
    }

public void userLoggedIn() {
    // do something when a user loggs in sucessfully
}

public void wrongCredentials() {
    // alert the user that he didn't put in the correct credentials
}

//AsyncTask
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // show a dialog window here when the AsyncTask starts
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings){
        try {
            user = repository.getUser(strings[0], strings[1]);
            if (user != null)
                return true; //wont work
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

       @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        // dismiss the dialog window here after the AsyncTask finishes
        if (aBoolean) {
            userLoggedIn();
        } else {
            wrongCredentials();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice replay! But i want to store `Login` `AsyncTask` class in diffrent java file. Is it possible to show something like process dialog in that `login` class?

Comment: "process dialog"? Do you mean "progress dialog"?

Comment: Yes, progress dialog

Comment: You can show the progress dialog (but since it's deprecated I suggest using some alternative - I just call it that for easy understanding) even if the AsyncTask is in a separate file. Just pass a context from the activity you are calling the AsyncTask from in the AsynkTask's constructor and use that context for the "Progress Dialog"